# Floating sidebar running into footer

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I have a simple one-page site built in Bootstrap that has a floating sidebar in it. Everything's working fine except on certain screen sizes, the sidebar runs into the bottom section and footer at the bottom of the page. How do I get it to stop once it hits a certain part of the bottom of the page? With an offset?

Here is my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* activate sidebar */
  $('#sidebar').affix({
    offset: {
      top: 400
    }
  });

  /* activate scrollspy menu */
  var $body = $(document.body);
  var navHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight(true) + 10;

  $body.scrollspy({
    target: '#leftCol',
    offset: navHeight
  });

  /* smooth scrolling sections */
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

});
```

[Here's](https://cppptx.github.io/rdf.github.io/) the site.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible, minimal example on jsfiddle or [bootply](http://bootply.com/new)? It seems to work fine on the external site

Comment: What browser size are you looking at it in? It looks fine on anything large but anything medium (like a macbook) or smaller, it starts to have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use affix [offset.bottom](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix-options). It should be set to the height of the footer along with some extra padding for space between the sidebar and footer.

```js
var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight(true); // true value, adds margins to the total height
var footerHeight = $('footer').outerHeight() + 60;
$('#account-overview-container').affix({
  offset: {
    top: headerHeight,
    bottom: footerHeight
  }
}).on('affix.bs.affix', function() { // before affix
  $(this).css({
    /*'top': headerHeight,*/ // for fixed height
    'width': $(this).outerWidth() // variable widths
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
header,
footer {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 40px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#account-overview-container.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px
}
.affix-top {
  position: static;
}
.affix-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: auto !important;
}
footer {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
footer h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<header>
  <h1>This is the header</h1>

</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <div class="well well-small affix-top" id="account-overview-container">
        <h4 class="no-top-margin">Customer Info</h4>

        <ul class="account-info-list list-unstyled no-bottom-margin">
          <li><strong class="info-title" style="width: 78px;">Name:</strong>
            <span class="info-data" style="width: 180px;">resold1 of reseller2</span>
          </li>
          <li><strong class="info-title" style="width: 78px;">Location:</strong>
            <span class="info-data" style="width: 180px;"><em class="muted">N/A</em></span>
          </li>
          <li><strong class="info-title" style="width: 78px;">Local Time:</strong>
            <time class="info-data" datestamp="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" title="12:00:00 AM" style="width: 180px;">12:00 AM</time>
          </li>
          <li><strong class="info-title" style="width: 78px;">Contact:</strong>
            <span class="info-data" style="width: 180px;">first last</span>
          </li>
          <li><strong class="info-title" style="width: 78px;">Phone:</strong>
            <span class="info-data" style="width: 180px;">8675309</span>
          </li>
          <li><strong class="info-title" style="width: 78px;">Mobile:</strong>
            <span class="info-data" style="width: 180px;"><em class="muted">N/A</em></span>
          </li>
          <li> <strong class="info-title" style="width: 78px;">Email:</strong>
            <span class="info-data" style="width: 180px;"><a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <h4>Business Info</h4>

        <ul class="account-info-list list-unstyled no-bottom-margin">
          <li> <strong class="info-title" style="width: 80px;">Website:</strong>
            <span class="info-data" style="width: 178px;"><em class="muted">N/A</em></span>
          </li>
          <li> <strong class="info-title" style="width: 80px;">Industry:</strong>
            <span class="info-data" style="width: 178px;"><em class="muted">N/A</em></span>
          </li>
          <li><strong class="info-title" style="width: 80px;">Employees:</strong>
            <span class="info-data" style="width: 178px;">0</span>
          </li>
          <li> <strong class="info-title" style="width: 80px;">Ownership:</strong>
            <span class="info-data" style="width: 178px;"><em class="muted">N/A</em></span>
          </li>
          <li><strong class="info-title" style="width: 80px;">Parent:</strong>
            <span class="info-data" style="width: 178px;"><em class="muted">N/A</em></span>

          </li>
          <li> <strong class="info-title" style="width: 80px;">Source:</strong>
            <span class="info-data" style="width: 178px;"><em class="muted">N/A</em></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Recent Notes</legend> <a class="space-bottom btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Create New Note</a>

        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <colgroup>
            <col>
              <col style="width: 30%;">
          </colgroup>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h4>hah notes!</h4>

                <p>I LOVE NOTES SOOOOOOOO MUCH!</p>
              </td>
              <td><span class="muted">Created on Mar 4, 2013 at 5:33 pm</span>

                <br><span class="muted">Follow-Up on <span class="js-datetime-date">May 06, 2013</span> at <span class="js-datetime-time">12:16 pm</span>

                <input class="js-datetime-ms" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Follow-up Date must be a number." id="n_FollowUpDateTicksSinceEpochUTC" name="n.FollowUpDateTicksSinceEpochUTC" type="hidden" value="1367860578340">
                </span>
                <br><span class="text-info">user@domain.com</span>

                <br>Type:<span class="label label-info">Billing</span>

              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h4>This is another note</h4>

                <p>Adipisicing etsy beard, laborum odd future mlkshk incididunt artisan. Tattooed officia banh mi typewriter est. Excepteur carles twee flexitarian anim, you probably haven't heard of them vero disrupt odd future kale chips 3 wolf moon jean
                  shorts laboris fixie. Magna anim consequat, selvage messenger bag pariatur occaecat you probably haven't heard of them tonx echo park fashion axe. Skateboard enim voluptate before they sold out artisan. Etsy single-origin coffee pickled,
                  ut meggings craft beer meh PBR mollit terry richardson trust fund tempor. American apparel pop-up wes anderson odio, ea blue bottle meggings laboris dolor.</p>
              </td>
              <td> <span class="muted">Created on Mar 5, 2013 at 2:14 pm</span>

                <br> <span class="muted">
         Follow-Up on <span class="js-datetime-date">Sep 06, 2013</span> at <span class="js-datetime-time">2:47 pm</span>

                <input class="js-datetime-ms" id="n_FollowUpDateTicksSinceEpochUTC" name="n.FollowUpDateTicksSinceEpochUTC" type="hidden" value="1378496859780">
                </span>
                <br> <span class="text-info">user@domain.com</span>

                <br>Type: <span class="label label-info">Care</span>

              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h4>banjo enim skateboard</h4>

                <p>Tonx direct trade butcher dolor, letterpress lo-fi kogi adipisicing locavore ad. VHS ut flannel readymade et. Helvetica cray cliche semiotics craft beer tonx. Placeat bushwick sustainable exercitation, ea banjo Austin art party raw denim.
                  Aute cillum helvetica umami mustache, forage ex pickled quinoa portland terry richardson sint duis. Messenger bag pour-over ut, tempor +1 fugiat irony pickled Austin yr placeat locavore literally ethical cupidatat. Est banksy meh, officia
                  carles kogi culpa viral hella nihil chambray lo-fi.</p>
              </td>
              <td> <span class="muted">Created on Mar 5, 2013 at 2:16 pm</span>

                <br> <span class="muted">
         Follow-Up on <span class="js-datetime-date">Jul 06, 2014</span> at <span class="js-datetime-time">1:35 pm</span>

                <input class="js-datetime-ms" id="n_FollowUpDateTicksSinceEpochUTC" name="n.FollowUpDateTicksSinceEpochUTC" type="hidden" value="1404671721721">
                </span>
                <br> <span class="text-info">user@domain.com</span>

                <br>Type: <span class="label label-info">Billing</span>

              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h4>This is another note</h4>

                <p>Adipisicing etsy beard, laborum odd future mlkshk incididunt artisan. Tattooed officia banh mi typewriter est. Excepteur carles twee flexitarian anim, you probably haven't heard of them vero disrupt odd future kale chips 3 wolf moon jean
                  shorts laboris fixie. Magna anim consequat, selvage messenger bag pariatur occaecat you probably haven't heard of them tonx echo park fashion axe. Skateboard enim voluptate before they sold out artisan. Etsy single-origin coffee pickled,
                  ut meggings craft beer meh PBR mollit terry richardson trust fund tempor. American apparel pop-up wes anderson odio, ea blue bottle meggings laboris dolor.</p>
              </td>
              <td> <span class="muted">Created on Mar 5, 2013 at 2:14 pm</span>

                <br> <span class="muted">
         Follow-Up on <span class="js-datetime-date">Sep 06, 2013</span> at <span class="js-datetime-time">2:47 pm</span>

                <input class="js-datetime-ms" id="n_FollowUpDateTicksSinceEpochUTC" name="n.FollowUpDateTicksSinceEpochUTC" type="hidden" value="1378496859780">
                </span>
                <br> <span class="text-info">user@domain.com</span>

                <br>Type: <span class="label label-info">Care</span>

              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h4>banjo enim skateboard</h4>

                <p>Tonx direct trade butcher dolor, letterpress lo-fi kogi adipisicing locavore ad. VHS ut flannel readymade et. Helvetica cray cliche semiotics craft beer tonx. Placeat bushwick sustainable exercitation, ea banjo Austin art party raw denim.
                  Aute cillum helvetica umami mustache, forage ex pickled quinoa portland terry richardson sint duis. Messenger bag pour-over ut, tempor +1 fugiat irony pickled Austin yr placeat locavore literally ethical cupidatat. Est banksy meh, officia
                  carles kogi culpa viral hella nihil chambray lo-fi.</p>
              </td>
              <td> <span class="muted">Created on Mar 5, 2013 at 2:16 pm</span>

                <br> <span class="muted">
         Follow-Up on <span class="js-datetime-date">Jul 06, 2014</span> at <span class="js-datetime-time">1:35 pm</span>

                <input class="js-datetime-ms" id="n_FollowUpDateTicksSinceEpochUTC" name="n.FollowUpDateTicksSinceEpochUTC" type="hidden" value="1404671721721">
                </span>
                <br> <span class="text-info">user@domain.com</span>

                <br>Type: <span class="label label-info">Billing</span>

              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h4>This is another note</h4>

                <p>Adipisicing etsy beard, laborum odd future mlkshk incididunt artisan. Tattooed officia banh mi typewriter est. Excepteur carles twee flexitarian anim, you probably haven't heard of them vero disrupt odd future kale chips 3 wolf moon jean
                  shorts laboris fixie. Magna anim consequat, selvage messenger bag pariatur occaecat you probably haven't heard of them tonx echo park fashion axe. Skateboard enim voluptate before they sold out artisan. Etsy single-origin coffee pickled,
                  ut meggings craft beer meh PBR mollit terry richardson trust fund tempor. American apparel pop-up wes anderson odio, ea blue bottle meggings laboris dolor.</p>
              </td>
              <td> <span class="muted">Created on Mar 5, 2013 at 2:14 pm</span>

                <br> <span class="muted">
         Follow-Up on <span class="js-datetime-date">Sep 06, 2013</span> at <span class="js-datetime-time">2:47 pm</span>

                <input class="js-datetime-ms" id="n_FollowUpDateTicksSinceEpochUTC" name="n.FollowUpDateTicksSinceEpochUTC" type="hidden" value="1378496859780">
                </span>
                <br> <span class="text-info">user@domain.com</span>

                <br>Type: <span class="label label-info">Care</span>

              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h4>banjo enim skateboard</h4>

                <p>Tonx direct trade butcher dolor, letterpress lo-fi kogi adipisicing locavore ad. VHS ut flannel readymade et. Helvetica cray cliche semiotics craft beer tonx. Placeat bushwick sustainable exercitation, ea banjo Austin art party raw denim.
                  Aute cillum helvetica umami mustache, forage ex pickled quinoa portland terry richardson sint duis. Messenger bag pour-over ut, tempor +1 fugiat irony pickled Austin yr placeat locavore literally ethical cupidatat. Est banksy meh, officia
                  carles kogi culpa viral hella nihil chambray lo-fi.</p>
              </td>
              <td> <span class="muted">Created on Mar 5, 2013 at 2:16 pm</span>

                <br> <span class="muted">
         Follow-Up on <span class="js-datetime-date">Jul 06, 2014</span> at <span class="js-datetime-time">1:35 pm</span>

                <input class="js-datetime-ms" id="n_FollowUpDateTicksSinceEpochUTC" name="n.FollowUpDateTicksSinceEpochUTC" type="hidden" value="1404671721721">
                </span>
                <br> <span class="text-info">user@domain.com</span>

                <br>Type: <span class="label label-info">Billing</span>

              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <h1>This is the footer</h1>

  <h1>This is the footer</h1>

  <h1>This is the footer</h1>

  <h1>This is the footer</h1>

  <h1>This is the footer</h1>

  <h1>This is the footer</h1>

  <h1>This is the footer</h1>

  <h1>This is the footer</h1>

</footer>
```

[View Example on Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/YN4CwrR7fG)